# Run Python Pyramid server in production w/o Apache

Tags: python, apache, pyramid, wsgi, amazon-ecs

So we used to run our Pyramid server with Apache in production. But we are moving to Docker containerization for easier prod deployments etc, and we want to adhere to the philosophy of "one process per container"..so instead of running Apache in the container + 4 python procs, we just want 1 python proc.

So my question is - is there a way to run a Pyramid server in production directly? Without using WSGI+Apache?

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-pyramid-framework-to-build-your-python-web-app-on-ubuntu

My understanding is that pserve is for development only?

Create an `application.py` file and fill it with the following contents:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response

def hello_world(request):
    return Response('<h1>Hello world!</h1>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_view(hello_world)
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Will the above work as a production-grade server?

Comment: The community has provided many deployment examples in the [Pyramid Community Cookbook](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/deployment/index.html). Pyramid is agnostic toward the web server you use on the front. Also to be more correct, "Pyramid server" is not a thing. "Pyramid application" is a thing. You might have assumed that the "p" in "pserve" stands for Pyramid, but it stands for Paste. See docs on [`pserve`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/pscripts/pserve.html).

Comment: @StevePiercy thanks, so as the question was trying to get at - our goal is to run one python process...so pyramid has api bindings etc, we want to launch a python server not "in the front" but instead as a single python process. Nowadays, it looks like there are "native python servers" available, whereas in the past it was more common to use apache or nginx in front of python.

Comment: @StevePiercy I updated the OP..do you happen to know if (a) that this represents a production-grade server and (b) if it runs everything as a single process? or will it launch the pyramid app as a child process?

Answer (score 1):

The latest official recommendation is one concern per container.  From the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) (emphasis my own):

> **Each container should have only one concern.** Decoupling applications
>   into multiple containers makes it easier to scale horizontally and
>   reuse containers. For instance, a web application stack might consist
>   of three separate containers, each with its own unique image, to
>   manage the web application, database, and an in-memory cache in a
>   decoupled manner.
>
> **Limiting each container to one process is a good rule of thumb, but it
>   is not a hard and fast rule.** For example, not only can containers be
>   spawned with an init process, some programs might spawn additional
>   processes of their own accord. **For instance, Celery can spawn multiple
>   worker processes, and Apache can create one process per request.**

In your case, your web application server is a single concern.  Running Apache+WSGI is totally fine.  Don't worry about the processes—That's Apache's job.

For a better understanding of the "one concern" rule, [this post](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/451/2367) is a good overview of what problems its trying to solve.

Comment: we'll probably go with Bjoern instead of Apache - https://www.appdynamics.com/blog/engineering/a-performance-analysis-of-python-wsgi-servers-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/stable/), which, according to their documentation, is

> ... meant to be a production-quality pure-Python WSGI server with very
>   acceptable performance. It has no dependencies except ones which live
>   in the Python standard library.

Waitress is a part of the Pylons Project just like Pyramid is.

Comment: I think Bjoern is the better choice: https://www.appdynamics.com/blog/engineering/a-performance-analysis-of-python-wsgi-servers-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Bjoern is a solid choice when it comes to running Python directly, where the Python server has WSGI bindings:

https://www.appdynamics.com/blog/engineering/a-performance-analysis-of-python-wsgi-servers-part-2/

https://github.com/jonashaag/bjoern